# Creating huge images

Tags: language-agnostic, image, memory-management

My program has the feature to export a hi-res image of the working canvas to the disk. Users will frequently try to export images of about 20,000 x 10,000 pixels @ 32bpp which equals about 800MB. Add that to the serious memory consumption already going on in your average 3D CAD program and you'll pretty much guarantee an out-of-memory crash on 32-bit platforms.

So now I'm exporting tiles of 1000x1000 pixels which the user has to stitch together afterwards in a pixel editor. Is there a way I can solve this problem without the user doing any work?

I figured I could probably write a small exe that gets command-lined into the process and performs the stitching automatically. It would be a separate process and it would thus have 2GB of ram all to itself. Or is there a better way still? I'd like to support jpg, png and bmp so writing the image as a bytestream to the disk is not really possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it language-agonistic then you only have two options:

- Either do as you have done or
- do it as the professional graphics
  applications do it. They keep the
  images on disk in full resolution but
  when loading/saving they don't
  load/save the complete image at once
  but at runtime create such a
  tile-based approach in memory (and only load/save the parts that are currently relevant).

The disadvantage of the second aproach is that you have to develop EVERYTHING yourself. You cannot use any OS image handling, image en-/decoders or anything else.

I had a similar problem some time ago and could solve it by using only 1/16bpp (especially as 32bit for images usually contains 8 completely unused bits which do not need to be held in memory - alpha channel). This means I mostly had layers of 1bpp images. However this obviously only works if you use your own application to consume the images.

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick has a component named [composite](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php). The docs say nothing about whether this tool has been built to be as memory efficient as possible, but it shouldn't take long to find out. The download page is [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php). IM is available on all major platforms, comes with a ton of APIs and interfaces, and can as far as I know used as a standalone EXE or as a DLL.

If composite doesn't work out for you, I'm pretty sure there are other tools around. This will probably be easiest to achieve with uncompressed image data - I can't think of a way of stitching 4 JPEGs together without having them all in memory (although I'm sure that has been already done, too).

Comment: Thanks Pekka, I'll check out the composite feature. I won't be able to ship ImageMagick with my installer, so directly using their feature is out.

Comment: @David you're welcome. But if you can't ship even external DLLs, then you will definitely have to roll your own intelligent stitching/swapping solution - certainly not impossible but a nut to crack! I'm sure there are open source stitchers around with good source code to get at least inspiration from.

Comment: I've written a small console app that gets automatically run. It didn't take too long, but it's still limited to 2GB of uncompressed image data on 32-bit OSs. Still, I think it should be fine for most uses.